# Second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Kindly help me with this...

$$U_{xy} + yU_{yy} + \sin(x+y)=0$$

Here $A =0$, so how to calculate the characteristic equations ?

as $$ {dy\over dx} = {B^2 \pm \sqrt D\over2A} $$

Comment: You have seen proper formula formatting alla $\frac{{\mathrm d}y}{{\mathrm d}x}$ in edits of your other questions - why don't you apply the knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=U_y$ ,

Then $V_x+yV_y=-\sin(x+y)$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0e^x$

$\dfrac{dV}{dt}=-\sin(x+y)=-\sin(t+y_0e^t)$ , letting $V(0)=h(y_0)$ , we have $V(x,y)=h(y_0)-\int_0^t\sin(\tau+y_0e^\tau)~d\tau$

$U_y(x,y)=h(ye^{-x})-\int_0^x\sin(\tau+ye^{\tau-x})~d\tau$

$U(x,y)=f(x)+e^xg(ye^{-x})+\int_0^xe^{x-\tau}\cos(\tau+ye^{\tau-x})~d\tau$

Comment: Thanks a ton !! @doraemonpaul